# Exposing Related Content filter

Tags: views

I have a content type for publications that has a Related Content field for authors (which is another content type). I would like to create a view with exposed filters, where site visitors could browse or search publications by authors.

I created a page view that displays all publications and tried adding a filter [Content: Related content (exposed)]. It works, however I need to enter author's ID rather than name. Is there any way to make the search by related content title rather than ID?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve that was adding a relationship for the referenced entity (authors in my case). As a result, all the fields from the referenced entity become available in the current content type.

After adding a relationship, I created and exposed filter for author's name and in the "Relationship" drop-down in the filter settings selected the newly created relationship.